# Display Call To Action bar on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

I am using the following code to load the bar on click but I can't figure our how to load it on page load automatically.

```
<script>
var autohide;
$('body').prepend('<div id="bn-bar"><b>DON\'T MISS OUT!</b> Only 9 seats remain for the Google Tag Manager training on May 22!    <a href="#">Book Your Seat Today!</a><div id="hider"> </div></div>');
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hider").click(function(){
  $("#bn-bar").animate({
    top: "-50"
  }, "fast","linear", function(){});
})
$("#bn-bar").mouseover(function(){clearTimeout(autohide);});
setTimeout(function(){$("#bn-bar").animate({top: "0"}, "slow","linear", function(){});},2500);
autohide = setTimeout(function(){$("#bn-bar").animate({top: "-30"}, "fast","linear", function(){});},10000);
})
</script>
```

Basically I am trying to load a the message when user enters my website and I will be inserting it via Google Tag Manager. Below is a page where I found the code:

[Creative Tag Manager – Ads, Promotions, and Visitor Messaging -Lunametrics](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/04/14/creative-tag-manager-ads-promotions-messaging)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the firing rule for this tag to the default 'All pages' rule will cause it to be included on every page load. To fire it only on the first pageview of the session or based on other conditions, look into the *When We Fire Them* section of the Lunametrics page you linked.

Comment: I did set it to fire on all pages but nothing happens.

Comment: I wanted to test it firing on all pages before I start messing with different rules.

Comment: Did you publish the container after you added the tag and the firing rule?

Comment: Yes I did. I have been using GTM for quite sometime. I also use Tag Assistant and everything seems to be in order. My datalayes are being picked up and events are being triggered and registered in GA so I know that its not my setup.

Comment: Nope. Not a single one.